# Default conversion fails when DatePicker.SelectedDate set to null

Tags: wpf, datetime, nullable, datetimepicker, ivalueconverter

I'm binding a property of `DateTime?` to a DatePicker's SelectedDate and DisplayDate properties. It's behaving exactly as I'd like, but I notice this error in the VS Output window.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to type 'System.DateTime' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: 'DateTimeValueSerializer' ValueSerializer cannot convert from '(null)'.
   at System.Windows.Markup.DateTimeValueSerializer.ConvertFromString(String value, IValueSerializerContext context)
   at System.Xaml.Replacements.DateTimeConverter2.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
```

I've been able to remove the error by converting `null` to `DateTime.Now` or to some other default date but that isn't the behavior I want - my DatePicker should show "Select a date" when the value is null, just like it does now.

Should I make any special effort to eliminate this error?

If so, how might I approach this?

### Additional

The `DatePicker` in question is part of the `ControlTemplate` of a `ContentControl`. Here is a slightly distilled version of what I'm doing:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=MyDateProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
            <DatePicker DisplayDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
                        SelectedDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

In actual fact the template is selected and the bindings set in code, but this generates the errors I'm seeing.

Comment: I am not getting any errors and ideally it shouldn't be since `SelectedDate` property declaration is like this `public DateTime? SelectedDate { get; set; }`. So why does it need converter to convert null to DateTime?

Comment: I'm as mystified as you. The actual code I'm using is somewhat more complicated than simply binding a nullable DateTime to a DatePicker, but the XAML I've added above generates the errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it out as following .I got it from [Here](https://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/binding-null-value-of-datetime-to-datepicker/)

```
internal class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value != null)
            return ((DateTime)value).ToShortDateString()
        return "Select a date";
    }
}
```

Import the Class into the `XAML-Code`

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:PathToTheFolderWhereTheClassDateConverterIs2
Binding data into XAML

<DatePicker Height="25">
    <DatePicker.Text>
        <Binding Path="FieldToBind" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <converter:DateConverter>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </DatePicker>
```

Comment: Works as advertised, I suppose. But now the output reads:

    'DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'Select a date' (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if available.

...and so forth. The entire block is too long to post in a comment.

Comment: This causes the same problem, this answer is wrong.